# Why is the zero module not the direct limit of every system?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $M_i$ be $A$-modules. Let $\mathbf{M}=(M_i,\mu_{ij})$ be a directed system over $I$ where $I$ is a directed set. I'm failing to see an obvious fact which tells me why the following statement is not true in general:
$$ \lim_{\rightarrow} M_i = 0 $$

Comment: Why would you think that is true? Have you looked at examples?

Comment: I don't know any examples yet. But I feel like I should be able to disprove this just from the definitions. If I define $\mu_i: M_i\to 0$ to all be the zero maps, then isn't it true that $\mu_i =\mu_j\circ \mu_{ij}$ for all $i\leq j$?

Comment: Yes. So what? The definition of direct limit has further conditions.

Comment: As a very simple example, take $I$ to be a point indexing a single module $M$ and check that the direct limit is $M$.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood the universal mapping property of the direct limit. I got it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reasonable way to prove something like this is to come up with a counterexample.

Let's consider a simple directed set, such as a chain: $M_1 \to M_2 \to \dots$.

What happens if you take a non-zero module $M$, and let $M_i = M$ for all $i$, and make the transition maps $\mu_i:M_i \to M_{i+1}$ all equal to the identity on $M$?

One can come up with even simpler examples - what if I took the directed set to just have one element?